# Django get_profile() method not working on extended User model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model in an app named `user_profile` like so:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and in my settings:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'user_profile.UserProfile'
```

But if I try:

```
u = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=1)
p = u.get_profile()
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'get_profile'
```

What am I missing here?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Er, you're trying to get the user profile of a UserProfile. I expect you mean to get a User, then call `get_profile()` on that.

Comment: OK. I thought by specifying `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'user_profile.UserProfile'` I got access to the `get_profile()` method. Also if I do `{{ request.user.get_profile.username }}` in the template I don't get anything.

Comment: So, if I do {{ user.get_profile.user }} the temaplate displays the username. But I cannot do `{{ user.get_profile.username }}` or `{{ user.get_profile.email }}`. Why is this?

Comment: Why would you want to do any of those things? Email and username are fields on the user model, which is what you started with! Why would you want to go from the user to the userprofile and then back to the user? Argh!

Comment: Because if I at some point expand the UserProfile, I may want to get those specific fields and the generic fields such as email. I though all of those were reachable via `get_profile()`.

Comment: How should I then get email variable in the templates? Ok I guess that `{{ user.email }}` works.

Answer (score 38):

To anyone else that gets this error by following the old documentation, `get_profile()` has been depreciated in django 1.7.

Instead you can just access the userprofile from the user as below..

```
u_p = user.userprofile
```

where `userprofile` is the name of your `UserProfile` class

<sub>You can also change to use the newer documentation by clicking on the desired version in the bottom right corner</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I am using Django 1.8 and `.userprofile` throws an error.

To get around this since I had profiles setup in Django 1.3, after upgrading to 1.8 I just changed `.get_profile()` to `profile` and it works.