# Which version of Django should I be using?

Tags: python, django

I have just taken over the code for a Django project with the following requirements:

```
Django==1.6.8
Pillow==2.6.1
South==1.0.1
django-grappelli==2.6.3
django-tastypie==0.12.1
requests==2.4.3
simplejson==3.6.5
python-amazon-product-api==0.2.8
MySQL-python==1.2.3
```

I am new to Django and was wondering if I should be looking to update to a more recent version or if it is ok to carry on using version 1.6.8? The version of Python currently being used is 2.7.6.

I don't at this stage want to get into making many changes to the code.

Comment: if it works, there is hardly any reason to update. the latest version has security issues right now, so...

Comment: Thanks @taesu that is exactly what I wanted to hear :)

Comment: I would say your question is opinion based. there has been a lot of updates since 1.6.8 and some of the newer features you may find useful. Just one of those would be the [changes to how you get a userprofile module](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26510492/1324033)

Comment: of curse there are a lot of improvements in new versions, but (imho) switching to versions >= 1.7 will be annoying and if you don't need to work on it anymore then it's not worth it.

Comment: The comments from @taesu and Jiloc ignore the fact that 1.6 is unsupported, so it is missing out on security fixes. The question is not 'are the new improvements worth it?', it is 'can I afford to run a vulnerable version of Django?'.

Comment: 1.8 (the latest)  is a long-term support version. So if there are no major impediments to upgrading, I'd say go to that one. Alasdair is correct about why not to stay with 1.6 in production for longer than you have to.

Comment: There is [some initiative](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/69fOquu8v-U) from the community to maintain security backports for 1.6. I would still recommend to upgrade to an officially supported version if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking as someone who just upgraded an app from that Django version, here are my experiences:

**The good**

- Upgrading to an LTS release is going to help you a lot going forward.

  - Security fixes - you don't want to run a production app on software that does not get patched
  - There will be a proven migration path to the next LTS release (I hope...)
  - You will have a long period during which you can upgrade the next time (since there will be a long overlap between two LTS versions)
- You  may actually need the new features if you will do new development.
- It is (IMHO) not good lagging to much behind on a critical component. The day you absolutely *have* to migrate, there may not be a clear migration path and a lot of headache awaits.

**The bad**

- A lot of things have changed, most notably South being replaced with Django migrations. You will have to retest the whole app thoroughly. Some third party dependencies may not work or may require upgrades, breaking your app.
- You will lose all previous South migrations.

**The ugly**

- There are a few gotchas with going directly from 1.6 to 1.8 due to issues with South->Django migrations. At the very least, you should try out the migration steps a couple of times on a copy of the production database.

Comment: My gut tells me I should bite the bullet and upgrade but I am totally unclear at the moment about how much work this will be. Is there any easy way to see if my Django project uses South? This question may betray what a novice I am with Django. I guess ideally I need some way to automatically analyse my code to point out what needs changing.

Comment: The line `South==1.0.1` hints at it, but unless it is referenced from your settings.py you are not using it. My recommendation is to time-box the upgrade, spend a half-day on a copy of the production app and see how far you get. If you don't have time to continue now, at least you know later on roughly the level of effort required. It is impossible to say how difficult it will be because it varies a lot with what functionality your app uses.

Comment: South is mentioned in settings.py as an INSTALLED_APP but I can't find mention of it anywhere else in the code so it looks like it isn't actually used.

Comment: Forgot to mention, check for a directory called `migrations/` in your app directory.

Answer (score 4):

**You should upgrade.** Django 1.6.X has been end of life for several months, and no longer receives security updates.

At the time of writing, the [supported versions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/release-process/#supported-versions) are 1.4.X LTS, 1.7.X and 1.8.X LTS. If you do not want to upgrade often, then upgrade to 1.8.X, as it is a long term support release and will be supported until April 2018 according to [the roadmap](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2015/jun/25/roadmap/).

You should always upgrade to the latest point release e.g. 1.8.4 to 1.8.5, to make sure you have the latest bug and security fixes. These point releases are backwards compatible wherever possible. By running 1.6.8, you are missing bugfixes and security fixes in 1.6.9 - 1.6.11. However, there will not be a 1.6.12 release, even though Django has had other security releases since 1.6.11, because 1.6 is now end of life.

Comment: Is 1.8 backwards compatible or is it likely I will need to change some code?

Comment: you must change something if you come from versions < 1.7

Comment: You will likely have to change some code. Read the release notes for [1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.7/) and [1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8) for more info. You might find it easiest to upgrade to 1.7 first, then to 1.8.

Comment: I did not have to do many code changes outside of `settings.py`. Migrating the database away from South is what I spent most time on. See my updated answer.

Comment: Is there a tool I can run to see what needs to be changed? I use PyCharm as my IDE

Comment: PyCharm might give some hints about deprecations. However I don't know of a way to upgrade smoothly without reading the release notes I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to make any changes to the code, only upgrade to django 1.6.X versions (for security reasons). I just looked in the page and the last version in 1.6 is 1.6.11, but this version is deprecated and shall not receive any updates in the future.

If you and your team are using something like virtualenv or vagrant and have a lot of tests, you could make the experiment, but since 1.6 a lot of things are changed.