# Django: User Profile in 1.9

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.9

RELATED: [get user profile in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460426/get-user-profile-in-django)

The above shows how to get user profile but i read that the accepted answer method is deprecated.

How would I create/get/use user profile in django 1.9?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django get\_profile() method not working on extended User model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183264/django-get-profile-method-not-working-on-extended-user-model)

Comment: Scroll down to the second answer on duplicate... (disclaimer: its mine)

Comment: @Sayse the .userprofile works. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    address = models.TextField()
    ......


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

The above code will create a **UserProfile** record whenever a new user is created on **User** table. Then you can access the profile details like,

```
address = request.user.profile.address
```

Comment: it seems to be working with address = request.user.userprofile.address instead. So when User object is being created, how do you initialize/set the address value?

Comment: ah i just initialized it in the if created block and it works

Answer (score 1):

`get_profile()` method returned additional informations about User. Currently, these informations can be stored in Custom User Model or in a seperate model which is related to User Model. You can do that by [simply adding one2one relation with User model to your custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model), or [by subclassing the AbstructUserBase model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Subclassing User Model example:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    ...
```

One2One Relation with User model example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```