# Django ForeignKey user authentication

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I have an extended user model in django.

```
class userProfile(models.Model):
        user            = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
        uniID           = models.CharField(max_length=6)
```

In addition, I want to log when the user goes into my system using:

```
class systemEntry(models.Model):
        user    = models.ForeignKey(userProfile)
        time    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I am using the django authentication model when the user logs in:

```
tempUser = auth.authenticate(username = myCredentials['username'], password = myCredentials['password'])
p = systemEntry(user = userProfile.objects.filter(user.get_profile().username=myCredentials['username']))
p.save()
```

Giving error:

> keyword can't be an expression (views.py, line 29)

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django get\_profile() method not working on extended User model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183264/django-get-profile-method-not-working-on-extended-user-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using filter, you have to use .get and the inside query is not correct, you should do the following:

```
p = systemEntry(user = user.userprofile)
p.save()
```

If you would likte to use `userProfile.objects.filter(user.get_profile().username=myCredentials['username'])`
You should know that it cannot be done this way, rather you should do,

```
userProfile.objects.get(user__username=myCredentials['username'])
```

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field.

I am not able to read the username field from the userProfile

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. One more error: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, User found

Comment: I've edited the post again for `p = systemEntry(user = user.userprofile)`. and if possible please where is the error appears, in which line. can you post stack trace