# how to display userena mugshot outside of edit profile page?

Tags: python, django

I googled around and saw various tries but none of them works for me. The ones that make sense to me are these two, which I have no idea why it won't work. By won't work I mean it doesn't show the mugshot but `alt="hi"`.
Here's my code. What did I do wrong?

In my html I tried

```
<img src="{{ post.moderator.get_profile.get_mugshot_url }}" alt="hi" / />
```

and

```
<img src="{{ user.get_profile.get_mugshot_url }}" alt="hi" / />
```

In my `views.py`:

```
def post(request, slug):
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)

        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        context_dict = {
            'post' :post,
            'user' :user,
        }

        return render(request, 'main/post.html', context_dict)
```

`models.py`:

```
class Post(models.Model):   
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I really don't know why it won't work...

They are absolutely different, if you read two any noobie can see they are different. I have no idea why the moderator put duplicate here....

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django get\_profile() method not working on extended User model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183264/django-get-profile-method-not-working-on-extended-user-model)

Comment: @Sayse They are not the same! I'm using django-userena, not profile model. /i don't get any error either. So please remove duplicate!

Comment: What `User` model are you using then? What version of django? Judging from how they set it up in [the documentation](http://django-userena.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#profiles), they absolutely *are* duplicates. You could probably prove it by doing it in the view instead i.e `user.get_profile()`. Oh and I'm not a moderator