# Show profile of custom user in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

hi i a working on a project  for that i have made login and registration of a user. now i want to show full profile of user.since get_profile is not working anymore so how can i get full profile of a user

**my models.py**

```
class Consultants(models.Model):

    consul_id=models.IntegerField(default=0,primary_key=True)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)

    last_login=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True,null=True)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

**views.py for login and registration**

```
def register(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        consultant_form = ConsultantsForm(data=request.POST)
        if consultant_form.is_valid():
            consultant = consultant_form.save(commit=False)
            consultant.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print consultant_form.errors
    else:
        consultant_form = ConsultantsForm()
    return render_to_response(
            'register.html',
            {'consultant_form': consultant_form, 'registered': registered},
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def login_user(request):
     context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        print type(username)
        print "username",username
        try:
            user = Consultants.objects.get(Q(username= username) & Q(password= password))
            print 'chala'
            if user.is_active:
                user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse("welcome......you are succesfuly log in")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your UkKonnect account is disabled.")
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("INvalid User")


    else:
         return render_to_response('login.html', {}, context)
```

i want to make       def full_profile and def edit_profile.
How can i get logged in user consul_id??
please help me

Comment: You don't have a profile model here anyway, you have a replacement User model; get_profile would have done nothing. Your question is unclear, what are you not able to do?

Comment: i want to see full profile of consultants who has logged in

Comment: @DanielRoseman i want to see full profile of consultans

Comment: And what is stopping you from doing that? Exactly where are you having problems?

Comment: i cant understand how to get consul_id of logged in user

Comment: Why is it not just `request.user`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django get\_profile() method not working on extended User model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183264/django-get-profile-method-not-working-on-extended-user-model)

Comment: by request.user i get django databse user name by which i am logged in.

Comment: @Sayse you understand my problem well...but this question's answer did not help me.can you please help me

Comment: The "user name by which I am logged in" **is** the Consultant object, because that's what you passed to `login()`.

Comment: Scroll down to that questions other answer..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understand you problem well.. Take a look at recommended way of extending User model:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Then you can do:

```
u = User.objects.get(username='fsmith')
freds_department = u.employee.department
```

In your case it would be:

```
class Consultant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    *your fields here*
```

1. Now you can use standard authentication forms and methods
2. You always can obtain consultant data as:

   ```
   request.user.consultant
   ```

Comment: I dont want to use that OneToOne field.I have all field in my COnsultants field